# How do i get the next lines in a file whenever any ERROR word come in a line in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file in which i need to check on each line.
Whenever "ERROR" word come in any line then i need to take the next two line after that line. I have to do this in pyspark.

for example:
Input log File:

> line 1
>
> line 2
>
> line...ERROR... 3
>
> line 4
>
> line 5
>
> line 6

Output will be :

> line 4
>
> line 5

I have created an rdd using the log file and using map() to traverse each line but i am not getting the exact idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Actually I am not getting much idea. I simply created an rdd using rdd = sc.textFile("log.txt") and then i am trying logic inside rdd.map() but not getting exact logic.

Answer (score 0):

what about something like:

```
# open your file as f
lines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if "ERROR" in line:
        print(lines[i+1])
        print(lines[i+2])
        # Exit or something you want to do.
```

Comment: We can do this while reading directly from a file but I need to do this in Pyspark using rdd fn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using windowing functions:

````
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# set up DF
df = sc.parallelize([["line1"], ["line2"], ["line3..ERROR"], ["line4"], ["line5"]]).toDF(['col'])

# create an indicator that created a boundary between consecutive errors
win1 = Window.orderBy('col')
df = df.withColumn('hit_error', F.expr("case when col like '%ERROR%' then 1 else 0 end"))
df = df.withColumn('cum_error', F.sum('hit_error').over(win1))

# now count the lines between each error occurrence
win2 = Window.partitionBy('cum_error').orderBy('col')
df = df.withColumn('rownum', F.row_number().over(win2))

# the lines we want are rows 2,3
df.filter("cum_error>0 and rownum in (2,3)").select("col").show(10)```
````